# Unity: Editor Window not Syncing

Tags: unity, synchronization, editors

I have four scripts:

- `Engine` has a list of `MovementWaypoint`s.
- `EngineEditor` simply displays a button to open the window (this editor will eventually do other things).
- `EngineWindow` will manually add `MovementWaypoint`s into the `Engine` `MovementWaypoint` list.
- `MovementWaypoint` just has some variables that are unimportant.

When running this in the editor, everything comes out alright. As soon as I click the play button, the `Engine` list is returned to `null`. I don't understand why, and I've used this before a bunch without this happening.

If you try and test this, the window shouldn't show anything, as it isn't working in the base form. Spending time formatting the window, at this point, is useless. I would also like to point out that I did try this with an int, instead of list, and it did work in play mode.

Why is it behaving this way?

To Test:

- Import all 4 script.
- Create an object named "Engine".
- Attach Engine script, make Debug Everything true.
- Observe debug (G - WE ARE NULL).
- Click on Engine object, click Open Rails Game Editor.
- Notice debug (COUNT:1 instead of WE ARE NULL).
- Click Play.
- Notice debug (G-WE ARE NULL again).

---

**Engine.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Engine : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<MovementWaypoint> movementList;
    public bool debugEverything = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (debugEverything)
            DebugEverything();
    }

    //Used to give "real time" insight into the list while trying to fix errors
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (movementList == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("G - WE ARE NULL!");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("COUNT: " + movementList.Count);
    }

    void DebugEverything()
    {
        Debug.Log("~~~~~~~~~DEBUGGING MOVEMENT~~~~~~~~~");
        if (movementList == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("\tWE ARE NULL!");
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Size: " + movementList.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < movementList.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("\tNumber " + i);
            Debug.Log("\t\tType: " + movementList[i].moveType.ToString());
            Debug.Log("\t\t\tPosition: " + movementList[i].endPos.position);
            Debug.Log("\t\t\tTime: " + movementList[i].time);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EngineEditor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Engine))]
public class EngineEditor : Editor {

    SerializedProperty shouldShow;
    Engine engineScript;

    void Awake()
    {
        engineScript = (Engine)target;
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        shouldShow = serializedObject.FindProperty("debugEverything");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Open Rails Game Editor"))
        {
            //open window
            EngineWindow.Init();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(shouldShow);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

---

**EngineWindow.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EngineWindow : EditorWindow {

    Engine engineScript;
    public List<MovementWaypoint> movementList;

    public static void Init()
    {
        EngineWindow window = (EngineWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(EngineWindow));
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnFocus()
    {
        engineScript = GameObject.Find("Engine").GetComponent<Engine>();
        movementList = engineScript.movementList;

        if (movementList == null)
            movementList = new List<MovementWaypoint>();

        if (movementList.Count < 1)
            movementList.Add(new MovementWaypoint());
    }

    void OnLostFocus()
    {
        PushData();
    }

    void PushData()
    {
        engineScript.movementList = movementList;
    }

}
```

---

**MovementWaypoint.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public enum MovementType { STRAIGHT_LINE,  WAIT }

public class MovementWaypoint
{

    // MOVEMENT
    public MovementType moveType;

    // Movement - STRAIGHT_LINE
    public Transform endPos;
    public float time;
}
```

Comment: Gnemlock, I updated the question to better reflect something easier to read including a short snippet on how to test this and replicate the problem. The problem doesn't happen when you populate the list in the Engine, it happens when the list is populated in the Window and pushed out to the engine and then played. Sadly, it takes all 4 scripts to test it proper.

Comment: Have you been using [SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) or [Undo.RecordObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html) to let the editor know you've changed a piece of data in the scene and it needs to be re-serialized? If the object doesn't get serialized before you hit play, then the last serialized version gets used.

Comment: @DMGregory Adding Undo.RecordObject does not change anything :(